# Display two buttons when row is selected in tableview using swift 4

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4

Is there a way to display the UITableViewRowAction buttons when user selects the cell (as opposed to how UITableViewRowAction works by default which requires tableview to be in edit mode).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
    {
        let shareAction  = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
            print("Share Button tapped. Row item value = \(self.itemsToLoad[indexPath.row])")

            self.displayShareSheet(indexPath)
        }
        let deleteAction  = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
            print("Delete Button tapped. Row item value = \(self.itemsToLoad[indexPath.row])")
        }
        shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        return [shareAction,deleteAction]
    }
```

Comment: Your question is too broad and too vague to be answerable. You say you want to "display 2 buttons when a row is selected" Display where? On the selected cell? On some other cell in the table view? Somewhere else on the view controller? What kind of view controller is it? Is it a subclass of UITableViewController? What do you want to happen when the user deselects the cell? Should the buttons go away again? Assuming the buttons are supposed to show up on the selected cell, should there be space for them on the cell and they just appear in that space, or do you want the cell layout to change?

Comment: Duncan, thank you for your comments.  I have added the answers to your questions as an update above.

Answer (score 1):

Its unlikely that you're going to find code in another answer that you can drop into your project and have it work, especially if that code was written in another language. You're going to modify **YOUR** code to do what you want.

In general, you should not manipulate your cells directly. You should set up your data model to contain the state information used to configure a cell. You might have an array of structs where each array entry describes the info to be displayed in a single cell. (If you use a sectioned table view you might use an array of arrays, where the outer array is your sections and each inner array contains structs for the rows in a section.)

Below is an outline of how you might implement this:

```
struct CellData {
   var title: String 
   var showButtons: Bool
}
```

Then in your `tabView(_:didSelect:)` method, set the `showButtons` flag on the previously selected indexPath (if any) to false, set the `showButtons` flag on the newly selected cell to `true`, and call `reloadRows(at:with:)` to re-draw the deselected cell and the newly selected cell.

If you allow multiple cells to be selected at a time then you would not clear the `showButtons` flag for the previously selected cells.

In your `cellForRow(at:)` method, use the showButtons flag to decide if your buttons should be hidden or not.

Comment: Duncan thank you for your comment.  Would you mind providing a sample on how to do that?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a free code writing service. I gave you a pretty detailed set of steps to follow. Why don't you make an attempt to do it yourself, and if you get stuck post your code along with a description of **where** you're stuck and w can help you. You'll learn more if you do it yourself than if somebody writes your code for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I am not going to mark this as an answer because unfortunately it was not enough to resolve the issue.  I appreciate your help and comments.

Comment: How is it not enough to resolve the issue? Have you attempted to implement the changes I've outlined?